# In which Stargate movie or TV series did the 'USS Excalibur' appear?

Tags: spaceship, stargate

I recently saw on the internet there is a ship called the 'USS Excalibur' in the Stargate series but I can't find which movie or the season it appears in.

Can anyone tell me where this reference comes from?

Comment: it doesn't appear in the show as far as i know. i saw an wiki about it being in service from 2020-2023, which puts it past the show, i dunno if its in a video game, or fan fic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The show you're thinking of is [Babylon 5 crusade](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Crusade). The ship was the [Excalibur](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Excalibur)!

[image]

Comment: I've downvoted for a few reasons; The ship isn't the USS Excalibur (it's the IAS Excalibur), it's not from Stargate and the OP has [already confirmed](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68786/in-which-stargate-movie-or-tv-series-did-the-uss-excalibur-appear/153647#comment141578_68787) that he was thinking of the Excalibur from Stargate: TNG. Also, did you need to use a screencap from a mobile phone?

Answer (score 24):

The USS Excalibur isn't from the Stargate TV series (or films), it's from something called [Stargate : The Next Generation](http://sgtng.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page); a "*forum-based Stargate role-playing simulation group*"

The game is set approximately 5 years beyond the end of the TV series in a universe where the Stargate program (and the existence of Earth's fleet of starships) have been made public.

The USS Excalibur is one of a variety of new ships introduced exclusively for the game. You can view a full rundown of the ship class and stats [here](http://sgtng.com/wiki/index.php/USS_Excalibur) and an artist's mockup is pictured below;

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There is no ship called USS Excalibur in the series or movies.

It is however a ship called that in Stargate: The Next Generation (a forum-based Stargate role-playing game).

If you want to read about the USS Excalibur you can do so [here](http://sgtng.com/wiki/index.php/USS_Excalibur)

Answer (score 4):

The [other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68787) [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68788) are right in that it's fan-made and used in the game Stargate: The Next Generation but that's not where it comes from. That isn't an artist's mockup of a ship from that forum game, the forum game took an artist's work and incorporated it into their thing.

The [BB-307](http://sgtng.com/wiki/index.php/BB-307) page has a note at the bottom that the art is by "Mallacore." The links above are for the individual ship, not the class it belongs to - the difference between the *Prometheus* and the 303.

Mallacore/RJB's deviantArt page can be found [here](http://mallacore.deviantart.com/). He's got a whole load of work on there and was active on a range of forums *and* showed his workings out as he'd create stuff, much of which is also posted on there.

The design is also on the cards to be used by the makers of a mod called Stargate Invasion for Sins of a Solar Empire. A couple of their designs also seem to take cues from his work (compare the rear/sides of his Ares and their Claudius). This kind of cross-pollination happens sometime in fandoms with popular, well-done stuff.

[image: Looky.]

Answer (score -1):

You can see it in Stargate Atlantis Season 4 finale "the last man", when MCay is in the future, and asks some questions to General Lorne, behind him you can see the Excalibur.

Comment: That's the USS George Hammond (formerly the USS Phoenix), not the Excalibur.